# I want to increase the size of the close button on the openbox

Tags: x11, windows, window-manager, openbox

I am using in the OPENBOX X- window.

Was subjected to increasing the size of the title bar, it is the relatively small size of the close button.

Can I file through rc.xml adjust the size of the picture?

I want to increase the size of the button and the Maximize button Picture of the I close .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find another theme with a bigger close button here

http://box-look.org/?xcontentmode=7402

If you intend to keep the current theme, you must replace those three icons by hand, enlarge it. You should find your current theme in `~/.themes/NAME/openbox/`

The `rc.xml` is irreverent from this.